# Changing CSS dynamically according to its inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Just look at my code
http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/GXAYa/6/

`#box_bg` is the outer gray box and `#box` is the inner black box. I used jquery accordion in the `#box`. What I need is `#box_bg` should dynamically enlarge or reduce its height according to the size of the inner `#box`.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't specify an absolute height: just use `height:auto`. With a static position of `#box` and some padding for the frame the `#box_bg` will automatically resize to its content.

See http://jsfiddle.net/GXAYa/18/

Answer (score 1):

Change `height:260px;` to `height:auto;`.

UPD: Add `position:relative` to the `#box`

Comment: @llia Frenkel If I change it to auto #box_bg is not displaying

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need the position: absolute, so try this as an option and see if it resolves your problem:

```
#box_bg {
cursor: move;
background-color: #4f575e;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #00000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 6px #00000;
box-shadow: 0px -3px 3px 1px #4f575e;
    overflow: hidden;
width: 245px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 150px;
}


#box {
cursor: pointer;

background-color: #24272a;
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #4f575e;
width: 225px;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 10px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GXAYa/20/).